# Return string object as XML object using Spring 4 in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-4

Good morning

I'm using Spring 4 with only annotations(NO XML configuration). I know using Spring 3, we can use

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cui", 
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces={"application/xml")
```

Now my method signature is

```
@GetMapping("/cui") 
public String cui() {
  String responseXML = // This is my final result object which is XML.

}
```

How and where should I mention that I will return a XML object, but not String object in the controller?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GetMapping(value="/cui",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) 
public String cui() {
  String responseXML = // This is my final result object which is XML.
   return responseXML;
}
```

Comment: @GetMapping(value="/cui",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) , you cannot have produces in the @GetMapping annotation

Comment: are you serious ? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html . Please read the doc.

Comment: You can have produces in RequestMapping(value="/cui", 
            method=RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).. But not in @GetMapping

Comment: Did you go through the documentation ?produces ?
@AliasFor(annotation=RequestMapping.class)
public abstract String[] produces
Alias for RequestMapping.produces().
Default:
{}